# Конкурентное программирование. async с отложенным await. C#

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency

Вот код, который работает, как и ожидалось:

```
async Task<int> Delay(int for_count)
{
    lock (thisLock)
    {
        double result = double.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < for_count; i++)
            result /= 1.2345;
        return for_count;
    }
}

public void SendMessage(string message)
{
    if (thinOut != null)
    {
        thinOut.Send(message);
    }
    else if (For_count > 0)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Delay(For_count);
            Continue.Invoke(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(message));
        });
    }
    else
        Send(message);
}
```

Загвоздка в том, что студия подчёркивает название метода Delay и предупреждает, что он будет выполняться синхронно, так как в методе отсутствует await. Правильно ли я понимаю, что это недостаток анализатора кода, потому что он не видит await в другом месте, или можно написать более грамотно?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88224/discussion-on-question-by-sawa-akisawa---async--).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сразу приведу минимальный пример консольного приложения, который можно скопировать и запустить.

Три варианта метода `Delay`: ваш, полностью синхронный и псевдоасинхронный.
Сделан замер времени выполнения с помощью `Stopwatch`.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static Object thisLock = new object();
        static Object thisLock2 = new object();
        static Object thisLock3 = new object();

        static void Main()
        {
            int For_count = 1;

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                await Delay(For_count);
                sw.Stop();
                long microseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
                Console.WriteLine("1  " + microseconds);
            }).Wait();

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                Delay2(For_count);
                sw.Stop();
                long microseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
                Console.WriteLine("2  " + microseconds);
            }).Wait();

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                await Delay3(For_count);
                sw.Stop();
                long microseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
                Console.WriteLine("3  " + microseconds);
            }).Wait();
        }

        async static Task<int> Delay(int for_count)
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                double result = double.MaxValue;
                for (int i = 0; i < for_count; i++)
                    result /= 1.2345;
                return for_count;
            }
        }

        static int Delay2(int for_count)
        {
            lock (thisLock2)
            {
                double result = double.MaxValue;
                for (int i = 0; i < for_count; i++)
                    result /= 1.2345;
                return for_count;
            }
        }

        static Task<int> Delay3(int for_count)
        {
            lock (thisLock3)
            {
                double result = double.MaxValue;
                for (int i = 0; i < for_count; i++)
                    result /= 1.2345;
                return Task.FromResult(for_count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Что сразу хочу отметить: ваш способ задержки будет делать разное время на разных процессорах. Чем процессор мощнее, тем цикл выполнится быстрее.
Чукча не дурак, чукча использовал слабый компьютер для тестирования. Ваш метод стабильно требует две-три тысячи микросекунд (т. е. 2-3 миллисекунды). Следовательно, вы уже провалили собственное требование: задержка на микросекунды (это вы упоминаете в комментариях, перенесенных в чат).

Как вы можете убедиться, второй вариант метода прекрасно работает без всяких `async-await`.
Но если вам важно именно асинхронный метод иметь (просто хочется или это требование интерфейса), то используйте [Task.FromResult](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.7.2).

---

В комментариях вам все дружно писали, что ваш код *синхронный*. Вы настаиваете, что он *асинхронный*, потому что вы добавили `async-await`. Но нет, если бы он был действительно асинхронным, то вы могли бы писать просто:

```
else if (For_count > 0)
{
    await Delay(For_count);
    Continue.Invoke(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(message));
}
```

Но вам *пришлось* оборачивать вызов своего метода в `Task.Run`, что подтверждает его *синхронность*. На этом обсуждение можно прекратить.

---

В комментариях вы писали, что ваш метод слабее грузит процессор, чем синхронный код. Дело в том, что в вашем коде компилятором создаётся конечный автомат, который выполняет переключение контекстов.
Ход выполнения будет такой: переключение контекста (процессор не загружен), выполнение цикла (процессор загружен), обратное переключение контекста (процессор не загружен). Как можно видеть, в общем времени выполнения процессор загружен работой мало. Но время-то идёт! И это время процессор мог бы тратить на более полезную работу, чем ожидание.

В синхронной версии процессор сразу приступает к выполнению кода с циклом (загружен полностью). После чего освобождается. И никаких ожиданий на переключение контекста! Вот и получается по вашим замерам загрузка 100 процентнов. Но это как раз означает эффективную загрузку процессора.

---

Если вам нужно исполнять задержки времени на десятки-сотни микросекунд, можно использовать [Thread.SpinWait](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.spinwait?view=netframework-4.7.2). Крутите цикл, проверяя истекшее время (см. пример использования `Stopwatch` в коде выше).
`Thread.Sleep` был бы удобнее, но он не может гарантировать время менее 15 миллисекунд.

---

Также посмотрите в сторону использования методов структуры [SpinWait](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.spinwait?view=netframework-4.7.2). Различия [SpinWait vs Thread.Sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9719357/5045688).

Если вам действительно важны микросекунды, то следует обратить внимание на использование *структуры* [ValueTask](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=netcore-2.2) вместо *класса* `Task`. Примечание: .NET Core.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88299/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-petrov---async-).

Comment: Ответить на тему не дало, потому результат здесь: https://d0tcom.livejournal.com/181140.html.

Comment: Статья d0tcom.livejournal.com/181140.html обновлена (улучшен C++).

Answer (score 0):

С C# решение найдено. Удалось избавиться от нервирующего анализатор async. Понятно, что async без await ничего не делает, как и наоборот. Просто не знал о Task.FromResult. Как и было, Delay вызывается в отдельной нити (код асинхронный). Провёл ликбез на работе, опираясь на работу Дейкстры шестидесятых. Сейчас пишу тест для выбора периода цикла. Выяснилось много интересного. Реальные значения задержки порядка ста микросекунд начинаются с периода в миллионы. И это на диезе! Почему то в отдельных нитях процессор используется несравнимо больше, чем в синхронном режиме.

```
    const UInt64 count = 1000000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        object mutex = new object();
        for (int i=0; i< 3; i++)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                int id =  await Delay(count, mutex);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", id);
            });
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Task<int> Delay(UInt64 for_count, object mutex)
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            double result = double.MaxValue;
            for (UInt64 i = 0; i < for_count; i++)
                result /= 1.2345;
            return Task.FromResult<int>(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Псевдо код.

```
mutex

void delay(ulong period) {
    double x = double.Max;
    for (int i=0; i < period; i++) x /= 1.2345;
    mutex.signal
}

void main {
    runThread(delay(1000))
    mutex.wait
}
```